# Stop wpa_supplicant from re-loading on boot, or kill it

Tags: networking, network-manager

Running Ubuntu 14.04. Im playing with controlling the wifi connections via a python script to scan, select and monitor SSID's, signal strengths, etc. After scanning and storing my wifi information in python, I execute iwconfig with various parameters to configure my wlanX to make the connection I want.

wpa_supplicant keeps getting in the way of this and I want to kill it, disable it, keep it from starting etc. I have been unable to stop wpa_supplicant from running. Cant figure out what service keeps restarting it no matter what I do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just uninstall it?

Comment: I can find no uninstall option for this. The I can rename the /sbin/wpa_supplicant file. And that does prevent it from running. But it also prevents the command iwconfig wlan0 essid somename key somekey from working at all.

Comment: You can uninstall the `wpasupplicant` package like any other package, but of ourse then you cannot use WPA... I'm going out on a limb, but try adding a line with `iface wlan0 inet manual` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. This indicates that you intend to configure `wlan0` manually and the system should not mess with it. I'm not sure how well it works for wireless interfaces, however.